# Regex for specified formats of number with "-" symbols

Tags: java, regex, validation

I have a textbox to accept the numbers with (12 characters) like below four format only

```
12345-1234-12
1234-1234-12
12345-123-12
12345-1234-1
```

I tried this regex

```
  "(\\d{4,5}-\\d{3,4}-\\d{1,2})"
```

But it is accepting below formats also, which is not my requirement, and i dont want below formats to accept

```
1234-123-1
1234-1234-1
```

Suggest me any other regex will works?

Comment: Define "no luck". What happened? And how did you use it?

Comment: It is accepting      1234-123-1      1234-1234-1      also which is not my requirement

Comment: Why is it wrong to match those other strings too? I don't see why they should not match...

Comment: You are most likely looking for anchors: [**with**](https://regex101.com/r/jV1wY7/2) and [**without**](https://regex101.com/r/jV1wY7/1)

Comment: BTW If you do want code block markup to work, you need to add a blank line before the code (in addition to the 4 spaces preceding each line)

Comment: What is your requirement? `1234-123-1` and `1234-1234-1` are matched with your regex. Try [`String pat = "\\d{4,5}-\\d{3,4}-\\d{2}|\\d{5}-\\d{3,4}-\\d";`](https://regex101.com/r/dX0zE4/1)

Comment: So, have you had time to try out the pattern above? Else, please update the question. Also, try `"(?=[\\d-]{12}$)\\d+-\\d+-\\d+"` regex (but `12345-1234-12` won't match it since the length is 13, and the regex requires it to be 12).

Answer (score 2):

Using a positive lookbehind, you can also check a different constraint. E.g.

```
^(\d{4,5}-\d{3,4}-\d{1,2})(?<=^.{12})
```

Checks, if the part of the string from the beginning of the line to `(?<=^.{12})` has exactly 12 characters.

Java example:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(\\d{4,5}-\\d{3,4}-\\d{1,2})(?<=^.{12})");
for (String s : new String[]{"12345-1234-12",
    "1234-1234-12",
    "12345-123-12",
    "12345-1234-1",
    "1234-123-1",
    "1234-1234-1"
}) {
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(p.matcher(s).matches());
}
```

outputs

```
12345-1234-12
false
1234-1234-12
true
12345-123-12
true
12345-1234-1
true
1234-123-1
false
1234-1234-1
false
```

If a string with 13 characters should also match, the lookbehind could be changed to `(?<=^.{12,13})`. (This would return `true` for the first input.)